# Regex to find repeating numbers even if they are separated

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will tell me if I have two or more repeating numbers in a string separated by a comma. For example "10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" would return true because there are two tens.

I think I am close. So far I have:

```
if re.match(r"(\d+),.+\1",line):
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Just convert into a list using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then convert that into a set (which will contain only the unique numbers in the list) and compare the lengths:

```
line = "10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

lst = line.split(',')
unq = set(lst)
if (len(lst) != len(unq)):
    # non-unique numbers present
```

If you want to use regex, you need to use `re.search` rather than `re.match`, as `re.match` requires matches to begin at the start of the string, which would preclude matching `2` in `"1,2,3,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,10"`. Also, you need to surround your `(\d+)` with word breaks (`\b`), so that `1` in `"1,2,3,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,10"` doesn't then match against the `1` in `10`. This regex will give you the results you want:

```
m = re.search(r'\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b', line)
if m:
    print('Duplicate number ' + m.group(1))
```

Comment: I've added a regex solution to the answer